# Outputting russian characters into the console

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to output a russian string into the console like this

```
сonsole.log("Привет");
```

But the console ouputs this ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ. How to solve this problem?

Comment: What encoding is your web site using, and what encoding is the source file containung that log message? A mismatch between the two is the most likely explanation

Comment: Are you using `<meta charset="UTF-8">` on your site?  ----  You can also declare your encoding in your JS IE `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="blah.js"/>`

Comment: Ow now i see. That worked. Thanks @ Pekka 웃 and @Zak

Comment: @AzamatAdylbekov if you are happy with the answer, please accept it to reward others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your site's (or scripts for that matter) encoding.

You can use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the `HEAD` of your site to tell the whole page to be `UTF-8` encoded. --

**OR**

If you just need your script to be encoded .. You can encode JUST the script -- IE  `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="blah.js"/>`

Either way you should always tell your site/script which character set you are using.